# Search results could not be loaded at the moment. Retry

Tags: plesk

I'am get the follow error when try access apps or categories apps under plesk 12:

> Search results could not be loaded at the moment. Retry

I have look at the follow article: http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/121173

And get: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'psa.smb_apspackages' doesn't exist

Under my

> /usr/local/psa/admin/logs

I do not have error logs for

> php_error.log

How to can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved please check the follow post at plesk:

http://forum.sp.parallels.com/threads/search-results-could-not-be-loaded-at-the-moment-retry.324794/#post-763196

Use the command:

> select count(*) from psa.smb_apsPackages where registryUid not in (select uid from apsc.aps_registry_object);

the article at plesk are current, reason for not work as:

> select count(*) from psa.smb_apspackages where registryUid not in (select uid from apsc.aps_registry_object);

the p from apspackages need to be apsPackages

Thank you @IgorG for let me know

Answer (score 0):

Looks like psa database was not correctly upgraded. Try to fix it with bootstrapper repair procedure.

Comment: I have update post at plesk forum.
By running bootstrapper not repair issue.

Comment: I'am look for any help about this issue. Anyone?